# View Variables in Python

Tags: python, debugging

Is there a way to view a list of all of my variables in python while the program is running without setting breakpoints?  Printing is too messy because I have a lot of variables that are constantly changing.

Thanks

Comment: If you need to debug at this level in Python, there might be something fundamentally wrong with your approach to writing Python code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe `inspect` helps you, but you have to filter the information then.

Usage like:

```
> import inspect
> a = 5
> f = inspect.currentframe()
> print f.f_locals
...
...
'a': 5
...
```

Maybe it's worth to mention that you cannot iterate over the resulting dictionary in a `for` loop because asignment to a variable would change that dictionary. You have to iterate only over the keys (at least that's what I just found out).

Example:

```
for v in f.f_locals.keys():
    if not v.startswith("_"):
        print v
```

Look at the first line: simply writing `for v in f.f_locals` would not succeed.

Comment: It's not strictly correct that you have to iterate over only the keys. The key is that `keys()` iterates over the dictionary to build a list **and is complete before it gets assigned to `v`**. This implies that just `dict(f.f_locals.keys())` would work if you really want to iterate over it as a dictionary, or you could save that in a variable if you want to do other stuff with it that assigns names. You can also use `f.f_locals.items()` fine, but not `f.f_locals.iteritems()` or `f.f_locals.iterkeys()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on Pydev (python extension for eclipse), you can easily watch your variables, however you'll need to set a breakpoint initially, then only step into/over your code.

Answer (score 1):

Grab a debugger: http://winpdb.org/ and then you can watch them and see them in there; however if you're just looking for a function to print all the variables defined in the local scope, just calls `locals()`.

Comment: Just as a note to the surfers: `winpdb`, despite its poorly chosen name, is a cross-platform GPL licensed piece of software. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your question is referring to python as a language (as opposed to "python as an ecosystem of applications and utilities"), AFAIK, the answer is "no" (not out-of-the-box anyhow). Of course there are a number of IDE's that allow you to use debug to see the values of variables [see [Sumit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8253521/146792) answer, for example].

However if during development you wanted a "live monitor" of a number of variables, you could use the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module, and define [your own Handler class](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#handler-objects) so as to redirect the information "live" somewhere. Setting the message to `log.debug` level would make trivial to activate/deactivate this feature by simply changing the minimum log level of your application.

HTH!

Comment: Addition: depending on formatting, your messages include the time, the current function and other info. You can set different "levels" to your messages, so that you can suppress messages below a certain level.